# Get everything between 2 patterns in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, awk

I need an awk/cut one liner to get everything between a pattern and last filename,
for example:

```
$ cat .exportfiles.text
/branches/WP_Fix/Code/SharedApp/src/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/ed/CorticonFinIncomeEntiyLoader.java
/branches/WP_Fix/Code/BEAN/Framework/ejbModule/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/entities/fin/Income.java
/branches/WP_Fix/settings/Environment/RT/properties/build.properties
/branches/WP_Fix/test/Environment/DEV/properties/build.properties
```

Desired output:

```
Code/SharedApp/src/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/ed
Code/BEAN/Framework/ejbModule/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/entities/fin
settings/Environment/RT/properties
test/Environment/DEV/properties
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `awk`/`cut`? Why does this command need to be "in one line"? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -e 's,/branches/WP_Fix/\(.*\)/.*,\1,' < exportfiles.text
```

Comment: That works, but I would make it more explicit (and therefore clearer, IMO) by changing that last `.*` to `[^/]*$`.

Comment: +1 for the straightforward. I would add a `^` before `/braches` though this sed line works for the example.

Comment: @MarkReed in fact you don't have to change it, thanks to the greedy sed. :D

Comment: I know you don't *have to*.  That's why I said "That works".  I'm just a fan of making the intent obvious, especially in something like regular expressions that's hard enough to learn to read...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `cut` solution for completeness' sake.

```
cut -d / -f 4- .exportfiles.text | xargs -n 1 dirname
```

It doesn't *only* use `cut`, because there's no way to specify columns starting from the last one going back.

Comment: Compared to a pure sed/awk/perl solution, this one has the disadvantage that it creates one process _per line_, rather than just one process.

Answer (score 0):

This line could work:

```
awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{sub("/branches/WP_Fix/","",$1)}$0=$1' file
```

the `"/branches/WP_Fix/"` could be a shell variable to make the line more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate `awk` solution that doesn't make you manage the separators yourself:

```
awk -v FS=/ -v OFS=/ '{ for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) { $i = $(i+3) }; NF -= 4; print }' exportfiles.txt
```

...golfed, for folks who like that sort of thing:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{for(i=0;++i<NF;){$i=$(i+3)}NF-=4}1' exportfiles.txt
```

But this one might be easier if you break out the Perl:

```
perl -F/ -lane 'print join "/", @F[ 3 .. ($#F - 1) ]' exportfiles.txt
```

..or

```
 perl -F/ -lane '$,="/";print@F[3..$#F-1]' exportfiles.txt
```

Comment: awk golf, 1)`i=0` could be saved 2)the `FS/OFS` could be moved to file to save the `-v space` 3) for loop doesn't need the `{}` 4) `NF-=4` could be taken out of `{}`, to save the `1`. like `awk '{for(;++i<NF;)$i=$(i+3)}NF-=4' FS=/ OFS=/ file`

Comment: @Kent: mostly good tips, but leaving off the `i=0`only works for the first line.  The final value of `i` becomes its initial value on the next line...

Answer (score 0):

Plain `bash` solution:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do 
    file=${file%/*}; file=${file#/*/*/}; echo "$file"; 
done < exportfiles.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] while IFS= read -r file; do 
file=${file%/*}; file=${file#/*/*/}; echo "$file"; 
done < exportfiles.txt

Code/SharedApp/src/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/ed
Code/BEAN/Framework/ejbModule/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/entities/fin
settings/Environment/RT/properties
test/Environment/DEV/properties
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F"/" -lane 'print join "/",@F[3..scalar(@F)-2]' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
/branches/WP_Fix/Code/SharedApp/src/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/ed/CorticonFinIncomeEntiyLoader.java
/branches/WP_Fix/Code/BEAN/Framework/ejbModule/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/entities/fin/Income.java
/branches/WP_Fix/settings/Environment/RT/properties/build.properties
/branches/WP_Fix/test/Environment/DEV/properties/build.properties
> perl -F"/" -lane 'print join "/",@F[3..scalar(@F)-2]' temp
Code/SharedApp/src/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/ed
Code/BEAN/Framework/ejbModule/gov/illinois/ies/business/rules/entities/fin
settings/Environment/RT/properties
test/Environment/DEV/properties
>
```

Above i have used autosplit.Instead if you want for pettern match, you can anyhow use this too:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\/branches\/WP_Fix\/(.*)\//)' your_file
```